# How to check the validity of an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation, object

I have the following object:

```
{
     "title": {
         "type": null,
         "message": null
     },
     "first name": {
         "type": null,
         "message": null
     },
     "lastName": {
         "type": null,
         "message": null
     },
}
```

How can I check whether one of the nested objects has the value `error` (of type string) for the `type` property.

If one of the objects has the value `error` for `type`, my method `isValid()` should return the boolean value false.

The object is used within the useState hook like this:

```
const [validateObj, setValidateObj] = useState(sampleObj);
```

..and I want to use this method:

```
const isValid = (): boolean => {
  return // hmm?
};
```

Comment: Do you mean whether _any_ of the values has `"type": "error"` (see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or whether a specific value has it (see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: For example if the title object has "error" for the type property, then the method should return false. The method should only return true if the object has no nested objects with the type attributes set to "error".

Comment: See that first link, then.

Comment: The some method is for arrays. I have an object here.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you look into how to get an array of the values you want to check given an object! Decompose the problem into small pieces, research and solve each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you're looking for:

```
const isValid = (): boolean => 
    Object.values(validateObj)             // get the list of values
          .every(o => o.type !== "error"); // check that no type is "error"
```

The documentation for [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/every):

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

Since you're using this in a React component, you won't want the function to get change on each render, but to only change when `validateObj` changes. For this, you may want to look at the documentation for the [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook.

Comment: You can F5 and check the latest version of the code, I cleaned it up a bit.